# How to add metadata to html by grunt?

Tags: html, gruntjs

I need to add to head in HTML reference to JS and CSS files.
How I can add metadata to HTML by grunt? Which plugin should I use and which way?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you already use. I use for similar purposes [grunt-file-creator](https://github.com/travis-hilterbrand/grunt-file-creator) which is really powerful, but you need some knowledge of Node for using it.

If you already use `copy`task then you can set up `process` function, e.g. like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724550/gruntjs-replace-templates-when-copying-a-file).

If you use `concat` / `uglify` tasks you can use `banner` option.

Sorry if the answer is not that clear, but your question is too broad.

Comment: I using concat/uglify. How I can use baner option when I need only add references to JS and CSS files between <head> and </head> tags?

Comment: well in this case you cannot. Just was thinking you probably adding something to the top of the file

Comment: So what plugin i should use to do this and how? At example it should searching in directory all JS files and add reference to them to html head.

Comment: @CezaryBorowy I cannot tell anything more. You asked about the direction and what / how to use, this is given in my answer. If you want to have a working code, please start it yourself and post it in your question.